# free space inconsistency

Tags: disk-usage

I'm running ubuntu 14.04. It keeps telling that I'm running out of space.

On the left my screenshot says that I have 6.3 GB free, but on the right it says 300MB. What is going on? How can I fix it?

[image]

```
ignacio@UltraPro:~$ df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.7M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       110G  105G  227M 100% /
tmpfs           7.8G   75M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       917G  446G  425G  52% /1TB
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           1.6G   60K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

---

[image]

Comment: Use `gparted` and see how many partitions you have on your `/dev/sdb` drive.  Chances are you have another partition or space that is not used on the actual drive, where your root `/` partition does not have.

Comment: @Terrance i added a screenshot of `gparted`

Comment: You are indeed running out of space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this answer right [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/573250/295286), Ubuntu reserves 5% of the disk space for the `root` user. Now, do this:

```
120 x .05 = 6
```

that's the space reserved for the root user, and is not touched unless the root user (includes daemons running as root) uses some space. And if you add your free space:

```
6 + .3 = 6.3
```

**In other words, file manager tells you the space available for your user, the disk analyzer tells you space available physically and overall, regardless of the user.**

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, run

```
df -h
```

Which will give you a more accurate reflection of your current usage. The GUI's sometimes are out of sync with the actual storage situation.

Comment: I added the output from `df -h`