# What are consequences of reducing storage allocation to root user in ext4 partition?

Tags: users, disk-usage, ext4

By default ext2, ext3 and ext4 reserve 5% of all space for the root user and to prevent fragmentation which can be reduced using the following command:

```
sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sdb
```

This will reduce the space allocation for root to just 1 percent.

- What are the consequences of doing so?
- Am I compromising the safety of my data just for a little extra space?
- Can I make it 0% for a partition that just has media files and is rarely changed or updated?

Reference : [What does the grey slice in disk usage represent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573211/what-does-the-grey-slice-in-disk-usage-represent)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7950/70524

Comment: @muru thanks for the link! It explains the issue really well!